# jQuery.Ajax Format Path

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple question that I can't seem to find an answer to. I want to format a URL path in jQuery.ajax() with a dynamic variable, such as:

```
/submit/{ZIPCODE}
```

Is there an easy way to format this in? (The {ZIPCODE} will be provided by a text box on a form.)

Comment: can you give us an example of the desired format that you want to get

Comment: Maybe I'm not being clear enough, but I'd like to replace {ZIPCODE} with an actual zipcode on the AJAX request.

Comment: So you want something like this **/submit/1234**
but excuse me for being curious why you want to get this format may be  if you give us a use case we will help you better

Answer (score 0):

Use normal javascript string concatentation, e.g.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/submit/" + "12345",
});
```

where "12345" is the value from your texbox

More Details here:
[How do I pass a textbox value to jQuery .ajax method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327666/how-do-i-pass-a-textbox-value-to-jquery-ajax-method)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Zipcode is available as an HTML `input` element with ID `zipcode`, you could do this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/submit/" + $('#zipcode').val(),
});
```

Or this:

```
$.ajax("/submit/" + $('#zipcode').val())
    .done(function(){
         // code to run when successful
    })
    .fail(function(){
         // code to run on failure
    })
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for jQuery.param http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/.

This method formats an object into a query string. For example,

```
var dict = { 
  zipCode : 78457,
  property2 : "hi there"
};
$.param(dict) // returns "zipCode=78457&property2=hi+there"
```